# Changing TailwindCSS Classes Values for Font Size according to Screen Size

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm trying to make the regular Fontsize Tailwind classes change their "rem" size depending on the screen being used.

E.g. text-base would be 1.125rem in screens with min-width 320px, but in larger screens like mind-width 1200px it would be 1.25rem.

Is there such a way to do this?

I was trying something like this but it didn't work :(

PS: don't mind the values I use for this example, I was trying it out lol

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        OS: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
      },
      screens: {
        xs: {
          fontSize: {
            xs: "2rem",
            sm: "5rem",
            base: "1.125rem",
            lg: "2rem",
            xl: "3rem",
            "2xl": "4rem",
            "3xl": "5rem",
          },
        },
        sm: {
          fontSize: {
            xs: "0.875rem",
            sm: "1rem",
            base: "4rem",
            lg: "57rem",
            xl: "5rem",
            "2xl": "10rem",
            "3xl": "2.5rem",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that by using that approach
Learn more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens)

Not recommends to use `@apply`, but you can easily acheive what you are want to like:

```css
.custom-font-base {
  @apply text-sm sm:text-base md:text-lg
}
```